# struts.config to struts2 conversion

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, struts

I have a pretty large web application that I am converting from struts1 to struts2. I have been looking into everything I need to change in the jsp files but I also have many java files that I assume will need to be changed as well. In my login.jsp file there is a directory included that has a Header.java file. In this file as well as many others, these two lines are at the top:
import org.apache.struts.config.MessageResourcesConfig;
import org.apache.struts.util.MessageResources;
What do I need to change these lines to in order to make it work with struts2?

Comment: FYI your post content states you're converting from S2 **to** S1. The conversion depends on what you're actually *doing* with those imports--you should *never* need to do that in S2 (and really, in S1 as well). Without code there's zero way to help. Please see the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page.

Comment: I am just asking about this particular part of the code. The 2 imports that I listed above. If anyone has any insight on this please let me know. I am wondering if I can just stick with struts 1 but I am using Java 8 and Tomcat 8. During my upgrade to the new tomcat and java I have been receiving stack overflow errors on all of my jsp pages that were working before. I thought maybe this had to do with using struts1 and thought that maybe a conversion to struts2 would be necessary. Any insight?

Comment: Not without any code or stack trace, no. Again: that you're importing a class in S1 provides no actionable information--how to replace it? Who knows--no clue what you're *doing* with it, or if it's even necessary in either S1 or S2. So the best answer anybody could give is "delete those two lines".

Answer (score 0):

MessageResourceConfig and MessageResource are Struts1 classes to handle the message resources files. You can find some info about this functionality in many tutorials and examples, like this: http://www.laliluna.de/articles/posts/struts-message-resources-tutorial.html. In Struts2 the same functionality is handled automatically by the framework, but to know how it works and what you should do I suggest to you to take a look at the official website of Struts2:
https://struts.apache.org/getting-started/message-resource-files.html.
As you'll see in the official documentation you won't need anymore the two imports.